# Beamer Bug: subsubsections are missing in ToC

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

For a large lecture (600+ slides) I need ToC slides that show the ToC only for the current section, including all subsections **and subsubsections**.

However, apparently this does not work. When I pass the `sections={<number>}` option to `\tableofcontents`, the result is a ToC that shows all subsections, but only the subsubsections of *one* subsection. In the MWE this is always the content of the first subsubsection, but in my larger lecture slides document, it is (for whatever reason) always the second subsubsection.

When I remove the `sections` option, everything works as expected.

Is this a bug? (I have tried beamer version 3.10. as well as the recent version 3.17)

```
% def\beamer@version{3.10}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand\InsertToC[1][]{
  \begin{frame}{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[subsectionstyle=show/show/show, subsubsectionstyle=show/show/show, #1]
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Lecture 1}

\InsertToC[sections={\thesection}]  % shows only subsubsections of one subsection
\subsection{Topic 1}
\subsubsection{Motivation}
\subsubsection{Conclusion}
\frame{Stuff}

\subsection{Topic 2}
\InsertToC                         % shows subsubsections of all subsections 
\subsubsection{Motivation}
\subsubsection{Conclusion}
\frame{Stuff}

\end{document}
```

Output of `\tableofcontents` with `sections` option (unexpected):

[image]

Output of `\tableofcontents` without `sections` option (expected):

[image]

Comment: There are various inconsistencies in `beamer` regarding `\subsubsection`s, as Till was clearly not keen on their use in presentations. I have addressed some of these over the past few months: could you try the very latest `beamer` release (3.17)?

Comment: @JosephWright: I had tried cloning the mercurial repo, but failed to use it as it contains all this unexpanded `\ProvidePackageRCS $Header$` stuff.

Comment: @JosephWright: Oh, I just saw that 3.17 is available on CTAN. Nice!  (I didn't look there, as in the past only very few beamer releases made it actually there. Seems that things have changed a bit since you have become a maintainer :-)

Comment: @JosephWright: I have tested with 3.17; the problem remains :-/

Comment: @JosephWright: How should I proceed from here? Can you confirm this to be a bug? Should I report it on the project`s bugtracker?

Comment: Please log in the bug tracker and I will take a look when I get a moment.

Comment: @JosephWright: Thanks, I have done this. For all others: The issue number is #193, details at https://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/issue/193/subsubsections-are-missing-in-toc-when

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, in the Beamer user guide it says "do not use subsubsections, they are evil" xD

Comment: 'Out and out' bug reports are not best suited to TeX-sx's format, so I've closed. Probably need to look again at the bug itself :-)

Comment: @JosephWright: That's perfectly okay. A look at the bug itself would be great, of course :-)